# Upload Blob to SoundCloud from Meteor Responds w/ ErrorCode 500 or 422

Tags: node.js, meteor, soundcloud

Our app records user generated audio on the client and then ships a blob (encoded as .wav) back to the server. These files work fine for writing to the filesystem or uploading to our fileserver, but using the exact same file results in a 422 from SoundCloud's API, when we try to upload the file. Moving the 'track' parameter into the main body of the request results in a 500 response.

I'm not sure what I've done wrong, and, yes, I've confirmed that the client_secret, oauth_token, and client_id are correct. Any ideas?

```
//Request portion of server method
result = Meteor.http.post("https://api.soundcloud.com/me/tracks.json",{
headers: {Accept: 'application/json'},
params:{
    client_id: appId,
    client_secret: appSecret,
    oauth_token: accessToken,
    data_type: "JSON",
    data:{
        track:{
            title: title,
            asset_data: blob
        }
    }
}
},function(error, result){
    if(!error){
        var responseJSON = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
        console.log(responseJSON);
    }else{
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: have tried the same using a mp3/wav file?

Comment: I've tried it with a .wav file, not with an mp3. I've also tried with a binary string. No luck, at this point I'm afraid.